# NodeJS Express session is working in localhost but not working in Linux live server

Tags: node.js, express, session, centos, ejs

I am trying to adjust my NodeJS Express project to **use a Session Timeout of 2 Hours.** **Default timeout is 10 Minutes** as I have checked.

Below I have attached my **app.js and login.js** files codings. While testing in localhost, when the session time is expired after 2 hours, it will redirect to Login page of my application. But after **Releasing in Live Linux Server, the Session is Expired in Default Timeout of 10 Minutes.** In Live Linux Server the **app.js file** is in the path of **/home/centos/myProject/app.js** and in the Live Linux Server I'm using **forever app.js** command to run the Application.

**My app.js file Contains :**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var logger = require('morgan');
const session = require('express-session');

var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var playerRouter = require('./routes/player');
var staffRouter = require('./routes/staff');
var mediaRouter = require('./routes/media');
var playerformRouter = require('./routes/playerform');
var playerstatsRouter = require('./routes/playerstats');
var staffstatsRouter = require('./routes/staffstats');
var mediastatsRouter = require('./routes/mediastats');

const twoDays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;
const twoHours = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2;
const twentySeconds = 1000 * 20;

var app = express();
app.set('port', 3300);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.set('view options', {layout: 'layout.ejs'});

// Define the layout file
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.set('layout', './layouts/masterlayout')

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: "CPLAppSession2Hours",
  saveUninitialized:true,
  cookie: { 
    //secure: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + twoHours),
    maxAge: twoDays 
  },
  resave: false
}));

app.use('/', loginRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/index', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/player', playerRouter);
app.use('/staff', staffRouter);
app.use('/media', mediaRouter);
app.use('/playerform', playerformRouter);
app.use('/playerstats', playerstatsRouter);
app.use('/staffstats', staffstatsRouter);
app.use('/mediastats', mediastatsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**My login.js file Contains :**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); 
const db = require('../database');
const path = require('path');            

// Middleware to parse request bodies
router.use(express.json()); // for parsing application/json
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  res.render('login', { layout: false, activepath: '' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const loginDetails = req.body;
    if(!loginDetails.UserName){
        return res.send({
          message: "Please Enter Username",
          success: false
        }); 
      }
      else if(!loginDetails.Password){
        return res.send({
          message: "Please Enter Password",
          success: false
        }); 
      }
      else if(loginDetails.UserName.toLowerCase() == 'UserName'.toLowerCase() && loginDetails.Password == 'Password') {
        req.session.user = loginDetails.UserName;
        req.session.save();
        //req.session.destroy();
        return res.send({success: true, message: "Success"});
      }
      else {
        return res.send({
          message: "Please Enter Correct Username and Password",
          success: false
        }); 
      }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**My Installed Packages in Local and Live Linux Server are :**

```
myProject@0.0.0 /home/centos/myProject
├── alert@6.0.1
├── aws-sdk@2.1569.0
├── body-parser@1.20.2
├── cookie-parser@1.4.6
├── debug@2.6.9
├── dotenv@16.4.4
├── ejs@2.6.2
├── express@4.16.4
├── express-ejs-layouts@2.5.1
├── express-session@1.18.0
├── forever@4.0.3
├── http-errors@1.6.3
├── js@0.1.0
├── morgan@1.10.0
├── multer@1.4.5-lts.1
├── mysql@2.18.1
├── nodemon@3.0.3
├── path@0.12.7
├── popups@1.1.3
├── react@18.2.0 extraneous
└── react-dom@18.2.0 extraneous
```

**How can I achieve Session Timeout of 2 Hours by changing Default Timeout 10 Minutes, after Session expired. Have to find that the session is not working because of my code or Have to make any changes in Live Linux Server.**

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the problem, but there are some things that are not right. `Default timeout is 10 Minutes` I don't really know where you got that number from, when I just tested in my application by setting it to `null` it defaults to a day, or will be deleted on a condition like exiting a web browser application ([express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)). Also, you can, but you shouldn't set both `expires` and `maxAge`, the docs say `maxAge` should be used.

Comment: @GreenSaiko - My application expires after 10 Minutes when I load the webpage in browser, I have given the **expires to 2 hours** and **maxAge to 2 days** properties in milliseconds as a constant variable in Cookie Session of my **App.js file**, In the above code reference you can see that, in **My app.js file Contains :**  section. Can you tell me how to set **null** by giving code reference or example.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you set `expires` and `maxAge` in your code, which you shouldn't do. Just set `maxAge`, as the session-middleware will calculate the `expires` variable on its own based on the `maxAge`.
To set it to null, change where you set the store options in `app.use(session({ ... })`. Either set the `maxAge` to null `cookie: { maxAge: null }` or just leave it away / comment it out
Still it's weird that you get 10 minutes, I tried the exact same values as you have and it sets it to two hours

Comment: I did some more testing. I used the same values for `maxAge` and `expires` as you have, two hours and two days. I'm pretty sure by now that your problem is caused by setting both of the attributes (and even with different times). Try to **only** set `maxAge` to the time you want it to be alive and **do not** set `expires` to anything. It should look like `app.use(session({ key: "CPLAppSession2Hours", ..., cookie : { maxAge: twoHours } }))`